# While inserting record into SQL Server database form asp.net web form its inserting twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am inserting values into a web form and submitting the web form. The record gets inserted twice in my SQL Server 2014 database. My web form code and code behind logic are below.

I don't know why the record is being inserted twice into the database.

Web form code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="register.aspx.cs" Inherits="register" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Social Login Form Flat Responsive widget Template :: w3layouts</title>
</head>
<body>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Social Login Form Widget Responsive, Login form web template,Flat Pricing tables,Flat Drop downs  Sign up Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Login signup Responsive web template, Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!-- font files  -->
<link href='/../fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='/../fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- /font files  -->
<!-- css files -->
<link href="login.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all" />
<!-- /css files -->
</head>
<body>
<h1>Social Login Form</h1>
<div class="log">
    <div class="social w3ls">
        <li class="f"><a href="#"><img src="images/fb.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li class="t"><a href="#"><img src="images/twt.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li class="p"><a href="#"><img src="images/pin.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li class="i"><a href="#"><img src="images/ins.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content2 w3agile">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <form ID="form" runat="server" method="post"> 

        <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" placeholder="Name Surname"  pattern="[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+" title="Firstname Surname" required></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" placeholder="Username"  title="Username" required></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="phoneno" runat="server"  placeholder="Phone Number"  pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required title="Phone number starting with 7-9 and remaing 9 digit with 0-9"></asp:TextBox>    
        <asp:TextBox ID="email" type="email" runat="server" placeholder="Email Address"  required ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" type="password"  placeholder="Password"  required title="Any number of characters or special characters"></asp:TextBox>
        <input id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" runat="server" type="password"  required title="Any number of characters or special characters"></input>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var password = document.getElementById("password")
  , confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

                function validatePassword() {
                    if (password.value != confirm_password.value) {
                        confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
                    } else {
                        confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
                    }
                }

                password.onchange = validatePassword;
                confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
            </script>


        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Sign up" class="register" OnClick="btn_Click" />
            <h3>Already have an account? <a href="login.aspx">Sign In</a></h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <p>© 2016 Social Login Form. All Rights Reserved | Design by <a href="https://w3layouts.com/" target="_blank">w3layouts</a></p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userId = 0;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=RISHIK\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Register;Integrated Security=True");

        String query = "Insert into Table_2 values('"+name.Text+"','"+username.Text+"','"+phoneno.Text+"','"+email.Text+"','"+password.Text+"')";

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Label1.Text = "Hjg";
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't execute it twice, then. You are doing `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` and `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Actually, I wanted to that my records shouldn't be same for any user, as it an registeration form, the records must be identical, I had implemented the code for it, should I edit my file?

Comment: What? I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: you might want to parameterize your query (see the SqlParameter object), seems like your code is vulnerable to sql injection.  at the very least, sanitize those inputs in your code behind to check for malicious inputs

Comment: Your code is textbook example of sql injection. You need to learn now to parameterize those queries before you get a visit from bobby tables. http://bobby-tables.com/ Also, you should wrap your connection (and any other objects that inherit from iDisposable) in a using statement. So your connection and the command in this case.

Comment: What I was trying to implement is, the records inserted by the user should be identical, there shouldn't be any field which already exist in the database( having same value). So, that is why i have used cmd.ExecuteScalar() and cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); in my code. 

I haaven't uploaded my switchcase for the code, should i upload it now?

Comment: What???? You are executing the insert statement twice. I have no idea what you mean by "switchcase". And I know this is a school project but passwords should never be stored as plain text. They should always be salted and hashed. Ask your professor to demonstrate that because teaching you plain text passwords is really awful on their part.

Comment: Sean best way to use hashing password? Like what alogrithms are easiest to implement? SHA and all seems too be quite complicated to implement, is it ok to encrypt the password using Ceasar Cipher or maybe Modified Ceasar CipheR?

Comment: No a cipher is nothing like encryption. It is confusing to used salted and hashed passwords until you do it a couple times then it makes sense. This is pretty far off topic from your question but I do think you should ask your professor to demonstrate a safe way to store passwords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this line

```
userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

is not doing what you think.  it will execute the insert statement and then return a scalar value.

then your next line:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

will insert the record *again*

this is what Blorgbeard is trying to tell you.

that is why it is inserting twice.

also - you should consider parameterizing that query.  taking the value of your user input and creating your query with those values without checking them is just begging for a sql injection attack

Comment: I got this, I guess, I should have uploaded my switchcase too. I got two questions actually. :/

Answer (score 4):

Use parameterised query , something like....

```
int userId = 0;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=RISHIK\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Register;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table_2 values(@Name, @UserName, @Phone, @Email, @Password); 
                                        SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phoneno.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password.Text);

con.Open();

userId = (Int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining the benefit of adding parameterised query? Secondly, what does this do ?SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)", con);

Comment: @RishikBajaj Parameterised query protects you against SQL-Injections attack and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` system function in sql server returns the last generated Identity value in its scope. I believe this is what you are trying to get in your `userId` variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, and yes, that is what I was trying to get in my userID variable, I have one more doubt, that is, I to only accept values which are different(identical).

Comment: @RishikBajaj pardon ?

Comment: What do you mean by "only accept value which are different(identical)"??? Different means they are not the same, identical means they are the same. Which one do you want? And the same or different from what?

Comment: I even got a switchcase ready for it, should I edit my code  and upload here?

Comment: Sorry, I meant only different, I want reject values which are identical, only accept values which are different

Comment: Sorry when I barge in, but I think he want to check, that there are not two entries with the same username or email.

Comment: Exactly H.G. Sandhagen

Comment: Then you have to check the table before insert: Select count(*) from table_2 where username = @username or email = @email;

Comment: `@username` and `@email` as parameters like above. If it return a number > 0 a user with this username or email already exists.

Comment: It depents how to use the information. If I want to avoid doulbe data, yes. If I want to return a message "Duplicate user" I would prefer the select. Handling the Exception thrown when inserting against constraint isn't easier and the code not better understandable especially for a beginner.

Comment: @RishikBajaj I would use an `Identity` column for `UserID`.  It guarantees the values will be unique and you dont have to worry about passing it a value.

Comment: @ H.G. Sandhagen yes, I want to send a message to the use that "user already exist". 

@M.Ali mate as I said above, then how will I send a message to the user if I use scope_identity function?